# Inject new xml using BeforeSendRequest from IClientMessageInspector

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, iclientmessageinspector

I would like to "inject" a custom XML text using `BeforeSendRequest` method from `IClientMessageInspector`. Here is the code I tried:

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{       
    String myXML = "somexmlcontent";
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(myXML);
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(ms);
    doc.WriteTo(writer);
    writer.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;
    XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(ms, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);
    Message newReply = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, request.Version);
    request = newReply;

    return null;
}
```

But it does return me the error "Unrecognized message version".

Comment: what is the value for `request.Version`?

Comment: Version = {Soap12 (http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope) Addressing10 (http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing)}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a copy of message prior to manipulate:

```
MessageBuffer buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
request = buffer.CreateMessage();
Message message = buffer.CreateMessage();
```

Then create the new message based on your xml:

```
request = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, message.Version);
```

You can also create the new massage setting the version from original request object:

```
Message newReply = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, request.Version);
request = newReply;
```

Hope it helps